# hobby: using tangency information at a point when drawing paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

Consider the following minimum not working example, where the first figure is drawn using "standard TikZ" methods, and the second using the hobby package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
\tikzset{tangent/.style = {inagle={(180+#1)},
                           Hobbyfinish, 
                           designated Hobby path=next, 
                           outangle=#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
            \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

            \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
            \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
            \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
            \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

            \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
            \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
            \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
            \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

            \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
            \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
            \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
            \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

            \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

            \draw (sp0) .. controls (csp0) and (cep0).. (ep0);
            \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0) -- (0, \y1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0)-- (\x1, 0);

            \draw (sp1) .. controls (csp1) and (cep1).. (ep1);
            \draw (sp2) .. controls (csp2) and (cep2).. (ep2);

            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
            \draw let \p1 = (cep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (1pt, \y1) -- (-3pt, \y1) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action: diagram drawn using ``standard'' TiKZ methods.}
        \label{fig:newton_method_1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
            \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

            \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
            \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
            \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
            \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

            \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
            \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
            \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
            \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

            \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
            \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
            \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
            \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

            \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

            % Using \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints to calculate the angle for tangent
            % tangent takes a degree unit angle
            \draw (ep2) to [curve through ={(sp0) .. ([tangent=\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{cep0}{center}}
                {\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}]ep0)}] (ep1) ;

            \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0) -- (0, \y1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0)-- (\x1, 0);

            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
            \draw let \p1 = (cep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (1pt, \y1) -- (-3pt, \y1) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action: diagram drawn using the \texttt{hobby} package.}
        \label{fig:newton_method_2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
line 79: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/inagle', to which you past. ...\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}]ep0)}] (ep1)
line 79: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/Hobbyfinish' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}]ep0)}] (ep1)
line 79: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/outangle', to which you pchor {ep0}{center}}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}]ep0)}] (ep1)
```

I got the `tangent` code from hobby's [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/hobby_doc.pdf) -- see page 17. I am trying to set things up so that I can use the tangent command in all my documents, which is why I am trying to use `tikzset`. That way, I can insert the snippet into my global *.sty file.

How do I sort out the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  The first is that you've not copied the code correctly from the example in the documentation.  In particular, you've misspelt the keys; they should be:

```
\tikzset{
  tangent/.style = {
    in angle={(180+#1)},
    Hobby finish,
    designated Hobby path=next,
    out angle=#1
  }
}
```

Note the spaces.

More seriously, though, is the use of `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints`.  This doesn't leave the answer in the stream, it stores the result in `\pgfmathresult`.  So to use it as you want you have to calculate it beforehand and only put the answer in the `tangent` key.

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{cep0}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}
\let\angle=\pgfmathresult
\draw (ep2) to [curve through ={(sp0) .. ([tangent=\angle]ep0)}] (ep1) ;
```

(The middle line is because `\pgfmathresult` is easily overwritten.)

In full,

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225878/86}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
\tikzset{
  tangent/.style = {
    in angle={(180+#1)},
    Hobby finish,
    designated Hobby path=next,
    out angle=#1
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
            \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

            \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
            \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
            \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
            \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

            \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
            \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
            \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
            \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

            \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
            \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
            \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
            \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

            \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

            \draw (sp0) .. controls (csp0) and (cep0).. (ep0);
            \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0) -- (0, \y1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0)-- (\x1, 0);

            \draw (sp1) .. controls (csp1) and (cep1).. (ep1);
            \draw (sp2) .. controls (csp2) and (cep2).. (ep2);

            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
            \draw let \p1 = (cep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (1pt, \y1) -- (-3pt, \y1) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action: diagram drawn using ``standard'' TiKZ methods.}
        \label{fig:newton_method_1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
            \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

            \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
            \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
            \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
            \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

            \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
            \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
            \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
            \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

            \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
            \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
            \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
            \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

            \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

            % Using \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints to calculate the angle for tangent
            % tangent takes a degree unit angle
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{cep0}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}
    \let\angle=\pgfmathresult
            \draw (ep2) to [curve through ={(sp0) .. ([tangent=\angle]ep0)}] (ep1) ;

            \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0) -- (0, \y1);
            \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0)-- (\x1, 0);

            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
            \draw let \p1 = (cep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
            \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (1pt, \y1) -- (-3pt, \y1) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action: diagram drawn using the \texttt{hobby} package.}
        \label{fig:newton_method_2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. It fixed all the errors I was getting. I still don't have output, because I have this error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. ...h ={(sp0) .. ([tangent=\angle]ep0)}] (ep1)`, but I am fairly sure its unrelated?

Comment: I don't get that error when I run the above code, so I can't help you there.